# Merging on Index and rearranging columns of a pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am completely new to programming and started learning Python recently.

I have a pandas data frame `df` as shown in image 1 and trying to rearrange the columns as shown in image 2.

Can you please help me to complete this.

[image: From]

[image: To]

Thanks and Regards,
Arya.

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Please check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn about asking answerable questions. Please also avoid posting code in the form of images, as that makes it difficult to extract data to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.pivot_table` like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,1,2,0,1,2],'Name':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],'Value':[10,20,30,15,25,35]})
df.pivot_table(index='index',columns='Name',values='Value').reset_index()
Out[8]: 
Name  index   A   B
0         0  10  15
1         1  20  25
2         2  30  35
```